# Feed a complex-valued image into Neural network

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

I'm trying to "learn" a relationship between a set of around 10 k *complex-valued* input images (amplitude/phase; real/imag) and a real-valued output-vector with 48 entries. This output-vector is not a set of labels, but a set of numbers which represents the best parameters to optimize the visual impression of the given complex-valued image. These parameters are generated by an algorithm. It's possible, that there is some noise in the data (coming from images and from the algorithm which generates the parameter-vector)

Those parameters more-less depends on the FFT (fast-fourier-transform) of the input image. Therfore I was thinking of feeding the network (5 hidden-layers, but architecture shouldn't matter right now) with a 1D-reshaped version of the FFT(complexImage) - some pseudocode:

```
     // discretize spectrum
     obj_ft = fftshift(fft2(object));
     
     obj_real_2d = real(obj_ft);
     obj_imag_2d = imag(obj_ft);
     
     // convert 2D in 1D rows
     obj_real_1d = reshape(obj_real_2d, 1, []);
     obj_imag_1d = reshape(obj_imag_2d, 1, []);
     
     
     // create complex variable for 1d object and concat
     obj_complx_1d(index, :) = [obj_real_1d obj_imag_1d];
     
     opt_param_1D(index, :) = get_opt_param(object);
```

I was wondering if there is a better approach for feeding complex-valued images into a deep-network. I'd like to avoid the use of complex gradients, because it's not really necessary?! I "just" try to find a "black-box" which outputs the optimized parameters after inserting a new image.

Tensorflow gets the input: **obj_complx_1d** and output-vector **opt_param_1D** for training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can treat complex signals as input.

Use a transform to make them into 'images'. Short Time Fourier Transforms are used to make spectrograms which are 2D. The x-axis being time, y-axis being frequency. If you have complex input data, you may choose to simply look at the magnitude spectrum, or the power spectral density of your transformed data.

Something else that I've seen in practice is to treat the in-phase and quadrature (real/imaginary) channels separate in early layers of the network, and operate across both in higher layers. In the early layers, your network will learn characteristics of each channel, in higher layers it will learn the relationship between the I/Q channels.

These guys do a lot with complex signals and neural nets. In particular check out 'Convolutional Radio Modulation Recognition Networks'

https://radioml.com/research/

Comment: Thank you for your reply! My input is a complex image (Amplitude and Phase) and I'm reshaping it into a vector, because I thought it's somehow useful, but you say an 2D image is better to process. I've also adapted you idea of processing the real/imag-part seperately in earlier stages, than combine them in later layers. How would I do it? "Just" concat it to an extended layer? Do you have any ressources/papers which could describe this? :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to feed complex valued numbers with out using complex gradients in your models is to represent the complex values in a different representation. The two main ways are:

1. Magnitude/Angle components
2. Real/Imaginary components

I'll show this idea using magnitude/angle components. Assuming you have a 2d numpy array representing an image with `shape = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)`

```
import numpy as np
kSpace = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.fft2(img))
```

This would give you a 2D complex array. You can then transform the array into a

```
data = np.dstack((np.abs(kSpace), np.angle(kSpace)))
```

This array will be a numpy array with `shape = (WIDTH, HEIGHT, 2)`. This array represents one complex valued image. For a set of images, make sure to concatenate them together to get an array of shape = `(NUM_IMAGES, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 2)`

I made a simple example of using tensorflow to learn an Fourier Transform with a simple neural network. You can find this example at https://github.com/michaelmendoza/learning-tensorflow